# Paypal Integration for users on my web panel

Tags: laravel, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I'm quite new to laravel and payment integration.
I want to give an option to my web panel users to connect their paypal account with their own personal account on my web panel to receive payments.
and I want to give them a connect button for them to proceed.

Can someone please help me achieve the same.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to do implementation of solutions for you. Try finding a solution yourself (read tutorial, documentation, etc.) and come back, if you run into a specific problem doing so. Then post your approach and the exact error that you're stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Log in With PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/), possibly with the Partner Referrals API, to have them log in and get their PayPal account ID. This can be set as a `payee`.

Alternatively, you can ask them for their Client ID and/or Secret for [a live REST APP](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications), which they can log in there to obtain.